# INDIRECT function with worksheets in excel

Tags: excel

I am hoping to create a two dimensional matrix with a the indirect funciton in excel using something like this:

`=INDIRECT(A12:A14 & "!C3:C11")`

The idea is, if you have A12:A14 holding worksheet names, with C3:C11 in each of those worksheets holding some data, you can easily gather this into a matrix for processing within another worksheet using this simple function.

After this, you could use `=MMULT()` or other functions with arrays like B12:B14, for example to do a matrix multiplication:

`=MMULT(B12:B14*INDIRECT(A12:A14 & "!C3:C11")`

Is there a simple way to do this that I am missing? For instance rearraging it with parenthesis or placing a SUM somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Array formula****

`=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B12:B14),N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&A12:A14&"'!C3"),TRANSPOSE(ROW($C$3:$C$11)-MIN(ROW($C$3:$C$11))),)))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Thank you so much it worked very well, I just added a transpose in front to get it into column form.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the construction

`=INDIRECT(A12:A14 & "!C3:C11")`

that doesn't create a matrix but it creates an "array of ranges". AFAIK you can only use that usefully with certain functions, e.g. the "IFS" type functions like `SUMIF`, so you can get the total count of positive values in those 3 ranges with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(A12:A14 & "!C3:C11"),">0"))`

Another function that can process that arrangement is `SUBTOTAL`, so this formula will sum all the values in those 2 ranges

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT(A12:A14 & "!C3:C11")))`

Comment: Hmmmm, so there's no way to emulate a matrix multiplication then?

Comment: I don't know an easy way to do that - do you mean that you want to multiply the whole of the first range by B12, the whole of the second by B13 etc? Presumably you might have more than 3 worksheets?

Comment: Right, and then sum them along the axis, as in a matrix multiplication

Comment: You mean something like (array-entered): =MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B12:B14),N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&A12:A14&"'!C3"),TRANSPOSE(ROW($C$3:$C$11)-MIN(ROW($C$3:$C$11))),)))?

Comment: @XOR LX **Nice!** - I recommend you post that as an answer. FYI when I copied and pasted that formula it didn't like the first `$C$3` part, I re-typed that bit and it worked OK, looks just the same though - do you get the same?

Comment: @barry houdini Thanks! Yes - strange. I've had this before: if you put the cursor between the "C" and "$" in that reference and attempt to move right, it's clear that there's some sort of non-printable character in there. Wonder how and why? Ok, will post as an answer. Cheers.